# USD stock investment with EUR base currency

Tags: stocks, calculation, currency

I can't wrap my head around this:

In late 2011 I used EUR to purchase stock valued in USD.

Dividend yield aside, the stock  advanced a lot. However, EUR/USD also changed quite a bit.   I am considering selling this position and I am unable to calculate how much net gain in EUR I would have made.

Can someone help with this, assuming 10,000 € were invested back in 2011 and based on only USD valuation, the stock price increased from $10 to $40 ?  Not considering any intermediate dividend payout.

Thanks.

Comment: The value in EUR will be $40 x _number-of-stock-held_ x _number-of-EUR-per-USD_ (currently 0.88). Take 10,000 EUR from this for your gain. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @TripeHound Looks like it. Please make this an answer.

Comment: @Dheer It almost seems to simple to need one, but will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your net gains in Euros can be calculated by working out what you would make from selling the stock (in USD) and converting to EUR:

> *current-EUR-value* = *current-USD-price* x *number-of-shares* x *USD-to-EUR-rate*

and then deducting the initial purchase price in EUR:

> *current-EUR-gain* = *current-EUR-value* - *original-EUR-price*

In your case, assuming you originally bought about **1,390** units (using an [**average EUR-to-USD rate from 2011**](https://www.statista.com/statistics/412794/euro-to-u-s-dollar-annual-average-exchange-rate/) of 1.39), and a current (as at 16 November 2018) USD-to-EUR rate of **0.88**, then:

> *current-EUR-value* = $40 x 1,390 x 0.88 = 48,928€
>
> *current-EUR-gain* = 48,928€ - 10,000€ = 38,928€

Therefore, your profit if you sold today (ignoring any commissions and dividned) would be **38,982€**.

---

From clarification in comments, you could make a "*what if?*" conversion back at the old exchange rate: use **1/1.39** (~=0.72) for the *USD-to-EUR-rate*. This would give a figure of 40,000€ for what the shares would have been worth if the 2011 rate had stayed the same. Under this assumption, the "profit" would have been 30,000€ which is worse than the "real" figure.

However, this calculation is somewhat meaningless, as the rate **has** changed. Indeed, the change in relative strengths of the two currencies *might* be one factor in why the price of the stock has risen as much as it has.

Comment: My bad. 

My main issue is this: Comparing EUR/USD to today from 2011, did the exchange ratio development positively or negatively affect the gains on the stock ?

Comment: You could make a "_what if?_" conversion back at the old rate (use `0.72 ~= 1/1.39`) for the _USD-to-EUR-rate_ to get 40,000€, for a "profit" of 30,000€, which is worse than the "real" figure, but that's somewhat meaningless... the rate _has_ changed. Indeed, the change in relative strengths of the two currencies might be one factor in why the price has risen as much as it has.